# Send additional arguments through socket.sendto()

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am new to networking using python. I was working with the `socket.sendto()` function. I want to know if more arguments can be sent through the function, along with the message string, like as in a `timestamp`. I just added a variable to the sendto function. but that throws `TypeError: Integer required`. Why is it so? How can I send an additional argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if more arguments can be sent through the function

Look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto):

> `socket.sendto(string, address)`
>
> `socket.sendto(string, flags, address)`
>
> Send data to the socket. The socket should not be connected to a
>   remote socket, since the destination socket is specified by `address`.
>   The optional `flags` argument has the same meaning as for `recv()`
>   above. Return the number of bytes sent. (The format of address depends
>   on the address family — see above.)

`socket` isn't a high-level interface; you send bytes and receive bytes. All of the data that you want to send should be encoded in the `string` argument and get decoded on the receiving side.

Comment: But since the number of bytes of my message is unknown, how can i decode the message and the timestamp seperately?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: Prefix your message with fixed-length header that states how long the message is and possibly the message type (if that's applicable).

Comment: The receive side would tell you the number of bytes received. The recvfrom() call returns both the buffer and the number of bytes read from the underlying layer (TCP/UDP).

Comment: The number of bytes read from the underlying layer has very little (if anything) to do with the size of the application message being sent.  You *cannot* do message framing by relying on how many bytes come out of the socket at a time.